# Programmatically create a fastreport.net TableObject

Tags: c#, winforms, fastreport

I'm using FastReport.Net as my reporting tool in my WinForm application. There I need to dynamically create a TableObject and populate it with data using a data source. A sample C# code is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You should probably refer to [their documentation](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/FRNetProgrammerManual-en.pdf), then.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply.. But I can't find it in the documentation..

Answer (score 2):

You can find it in the Demo in Table tab.
The following can be useful:

```
private void Table1_ManualBuild(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // get the data source by its name
      DataSourceBase columnData = Report.GetDataSource("Employees");
      // init the data source
      columnData.Init();

      // print the first table column - it is a header
      Table1.PrintColumn(0);
      // each PrintColumn call must be followed by either PrintRow or PrintRows call
      // to print cells on the column
      Table1.PrintRows();

      // now enumerate the data source and print the table body
      while (columnData.HasMoreRows)
      {
        // print the table body  
        Table1.PrintColumn(1);
        Table1.PrintRows();

        // go next data source row
        columnData.Next();
      }

      // print the last table column - it is a footer
      Table1.PrintColumn(2);
      Table1.PrintRows();
    }

private void Table1_ManualBuild(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // get the master data source
  DataSourceBase masterData = Report.GetDataSource("Categories");
  // get the detail data source
  DataSourceBase detailData = Report.GetDataSource("Products");

  // init the master data source
  masterData.Init();

  while (masterData.HasMoreRows)
  {
    // print first 3 rows that contains data from master data source
    Table1.PrintRow(0);
    Table1.PrintColumns();
    Table1.PrintRow(1);
    Table1.PrintColumns();
    Table1.PrintRow(2);
    Table1.PrintColumns();

    // init the detail data source. Pass masterData to allow master-detail relation
    detailData.Init(masterData);

    // print detail header
    Table1.PrintRow(3);
    Table1.PrintColumns();

    // print detail rows
    while (detailData.HasMoreRows)
    {
      // print the detail row
      Table1.PrintRow(4);
      Table1.PrintColumns();

      // go next data source row
      detailData.Next();
    }

    // print the detail footer row
    Table1.PrintRow(5);
    Table1.PrintColumns();
    Table1.PrintRow(6);
    Table1.PrintColumns();

    // go next data source row
    masterData.Next();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying the below code in order to create dynamic TableObject in FastReport

```
    Report report = new Report();
    
    ReportPage page = new ReportPage();

    DataBand dataBand = new DataBand();
    dataBand.Name = "dataBand";
    dataBand.Height = Units.Centimeters * 24.7f;
    int columnCount = 4;
    int rowCount = 20;
    
                for (int i = 0; i < columnCount; i++)
                {
                    TableColumn tableColumn = new TableColumn();
                    tableColumn.Width = Units.Centimeters * 4.75f;
                    table.Columns.Insert(i, tableColumn);
                }
    
                // create DataBand --> create table --> and then creating rows and cells
                for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
                {
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                    tableRow.Height = row == 0 ? Units.Centimeters * 1f : Units.Centimeters * 1f;
                    table.Rows.Insert(row, tableRow);
    
                    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
                    {
                        table[col, row].Border.Lines = BorderLines.All;
                        table[col, row].HorzAlign = HorzAlign.Center;
                        table[col, row].VertAlign = VertAlign.Center;
                        table[col, row].ParagraphFormat = new ParagraphFormat();
                        table[col, row].ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = Units.Centimeters * .1f;
                        table[col, row].Font = new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
    
                        if (row % 2 == 0)
                        {
                            table[col, row].FillColor = Color.LightGray;
                        }
    
                        if (row >= 1)
                        {
                            table[col, row].Text = "Testing Obj";
                        }                   
                        else if (row == 0)
                        {
                            table[col, row].Text = "Column_" + col.ToString();
                            table[col, row].FillColor = Color.LightBlue;
                            table[col, row].Font = new Font("Tahoma", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                        }
                    }
    
                }
dataBand.AddChild(table);
page.Bands.Add(dataBand); 

report.Pages.Add(page);
```